# Manipulating Excel files using R

Tags: r, excel

I want to edit an existing excel file using R. For example, ExcelFile_1 has the data, and I need to place the data from ExcelFile_1 into another file called ExcelFile_2. This is based on the column and row names.
**ExcelFile_1:**
Store   Shipped Qty
1111    100
2222    200

**ExcelFile_2:**
Store   Shipped Qty
1111
2222

If I m working with a data frame, I generally do
ExcelFile_2$`Shipped Qty` <- 
ExcelFile_1$`Shipped Qty`[match(ExcelFile_1$`Store #`, ExcelFile_2$`Store  #`)

The above line works for my data frame, but I donot know how to place this formula while writing into a worksheet using XLConnect package. All I see is the below mentioned options.
writeWorksheet(object,data,sheet,**startRow**,**startCol**,header,rownames)

I do not want to edit as a data frame and save the data frame as another "worksheet" in an existing/new Excel File, as I want to preserve the ExcelFile_2 formats.
For example: I want to change the value of ExcelFile_2 cell "B2"  using the values from another sheet.

Could anyone please help me with the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files are stored in your home directory and named `one.xlsx` and `two.xlsx`, you can do the following:

```
library(XLConnect)

# Load content of the first sheet of one.xlsx
df1 <- readWorksheetFromFile("~/one.xlsx", 1)

# Do what you like to df1 ...

# Write df1 to the first sheet of two.xlsx
wb2 <- loadWorkbook("~/two.xlsx")
writeWorksheet(wb2, df1, sheet = 1)
saveWorkbook(wb2)
```

If needed, you can also use `startRow` and `startCol` in both `readWorksheetFromFile()` and `writeWorksheet()` to specify exact rows and columns and `header` to specify if you want to read/write the headers.